# Json format to unbeautify json

Tags: json

I have a beautified Json object and i would like to unbeautify it so i can use it in hard coding.

There are plenty of tools to beautify a json but none that would reverse. 
My problem is that i am not able to reverse the json object after beautifying it--- also known prettify.

I have already tried looking up if there would be any tool or site that will do this but was not successful.

Here is a sample of the json object i currently have:

```
"itemsList": [{
        "name": "Name",
        "type": "1"
    }]
```

Comment: What is the expected output? All whitespace removed? What prevents you from using hard-coded readable JSON?

Comment: @Robert I had the hard-coded but after beautifying it to make it readable and to make the needed changes i wanted to return it to original format without any spaces or lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use JSONLint's `reformat` parameter: https://jsonlint.com/?reformat=compress.

This can even be chained with the `json` parameter to pass through your JSON directly:

```
https://jsonlint.com/?reformat=compress&json={"itemsList": [{ "name": "Name", "type": "1" }]}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following.

1. Open Notepad++.
2. Use Ctrl+H and enable regular expression search
3. Find "^\s{2,}" and replace it with ""
4. Find "\n" and replace it with ""

Answer (score 2):

I do something similar to what RKS has mentioned using **only** Notepad++:

- `Cntrl + H` and then enable Regular expression
- Find `^\s` and Replace with no value (i.e. empty): to remove beautified json indent
- Find `\s+$` and Replace with no value (i.e. empty): to remove trailing spaces
- `Cntrl + A` and then `Cntrl + J`: to join the lines

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use https://jsonformatter.org/json-pretty-print. Paste your prettified json into the left hand side, and the second option in the tools above is to make it compact, removing all whitespace

Comment: I believe Shawn's answer is outdated and he was talking about:
https://jsonformatter.org/json-minify